# Swift - Value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> NotesListViewController' has no member stack?

Tags: swift3, ios10, xcode8

I write my self CoreDataStack file, when i compile the project, get a warning "Swift - Value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> NotesListViewController' has no member stack?"

```
class NotesListViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    var stack: CoreDataStack = CoreDataStack(modelName:"UnCloudNotesDataModel", storeName:"UnCloudNotes")

    lazy var notes: NSFetchedResultsController = { (_) -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> in
        var request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Note")
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateCreated", ascending: false)]
        var notes = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.stack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        notes.delegate = self
        return notes
    }()
```

Comment: when I write "NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.stack.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)", get the warning.

Comment: The declaration of a lazy initialized `NSFetchedResultsController` is supposed to be `lazy var notes: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = { ... )()`. And the stack, request and controller are constants (`let`)

Comment: @zonebin have you get any solution i am facing same issue